# Multiple File Replace in Ruby Chef Recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Chef newbie here and also know a little of Ruby.

I am not sure why I cannot write twice in a file in a sample recipe that I am working on.

I have two patterns in my config file that I need to replace but doing this 
does not update the two pattern; only one is updated and not the other.

```
ruby_block " Update Config File " do
  block do
    file_name = config_file
    text = File.read(file_name)
    File.write(file_name, text.gsub(search_value, replace_value))
    File.write(file_name, text.gsub(second_search_value, second_replace_value))
  end
  only_if { File.exists?("#{config_file}") }
end
```

I know I can do another ruby_block but I am just wondering what I am missing to make this work.  I want only one ruby_block instead of two since I am editing the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look line by line:

1. `text = File.read(file_name)`

Easy, we **read* the file content into `text`

2. `File.write(file_name, text.gsub(search_value, replace_value))`

We do a `g`lobal `sub`stitution in the original `text` and write it into the file

3. `File.write(file_name, text.gsub(second_search_value, second_replace_value))`

We do a `g`lobal `sub`stitution in the original `text` and write it into the file

Of course you're overwriting the changes in 2. when you write in 3.

One possible way would be to gsub twice and write only once at end, but really don't do that, doing this kind of changes is brittle and subject to break at any time or to insert changes at every run and break your configuration.
Let chef manage the whole file with a [`template`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) ,

Comment: Just to echo the bottom part, using a template resource really is better because it's a more convergent approach. As it stands in your example, you risk unexpected replacements if your regexps aren't carefully written.